# Why SAAW(ṣall Allāhu ʿalay-hi wa-sallam) is more common after Prophet Muhammad's name than SWT(Subhanahu wa ta'ala) after Allah's name?

Tags: practical-islam

Everywhere in Islamic gatherings or events, the translation of the Quran, and Islamic literatures, I see SAAW very commonly used after the Prophet Muhammad's name. However, I don't see SWT with the same frequency after Allah's(SWT) name. As to every Muslim Allah(SWT) is the supreme power and owner of all things, shouldn't this be the other way around? In other words, why the name of Prophet Mohammad receives more respect than that of Allah(SWT)?

Answer (score 1):

There is a direct command from Allah to Muslims to say SAAW when the Prophet is mentioned:

> إِنَّ اللَّهَ وَمَلَائِكَتَهُ يُصَلُّونَ عَلَى النَّبِيِّ ۚ يَا أَيُّهَا الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا صَلُّوا عَلَيْهِ وَسَلِّمُوا تَسْلِيمًا
>
> *Sahih International Translation*
>
> Indeed, Allah confers blessing upon the Prophet, and His angels [ask Him to do so]. O you who have believed, ask [ Allah to confer] blessing upon him and ask [ Allah to grant him] peace.
>
> [[Surat Al-'Aĥzāb:56]](http://quran.com/33/56)

It's the order of Allah that we say SAAW whenever the Prophet is mentioned. So we respect Prophet the because Allah ordered us to do so, this obviously means that we respect Allah more, and in obedience for his order we respect the Prophet that much.

However, there is no "solid" order that states we should say SWT whenever Allah's name is mentioned (at least not to my knowledge). But, of course, it's better to always say SWT (or other glorification words) when Allah's name is mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

In many countries, the prophet peace be upon him name is almost always followed by blessing but Allah subhan wa'ta'la name is almost never followed by any any blessing. This is because Allah (SWT) directs us in [Ahzab 33:56](http://quran.com/33/56) to say blessing on the prophet and use proper salutation with his name.

> Surely Allah and His angels bless the Prophet; O you who believe! call
>   for (Divine) blessings on him and salute him with a (becoming)
>   salutation.

I am not aware of any verse of hadith that asks us to do the same for Allah (SWT). In fact in hadith books, the phrase Subḥānahu ūta'āla  ([Glorified and Exalted be He](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subhanahu_wa_ta%27ala)) is never used or used very rarely. In my view this is just innovation. One example of such hadith is below.

> حَدَّثَنِي مَخْلَدُ بْنُ مَالِكٍ، حَدَّثَنَا يَحْيَى بْنُ سَعِيدٍ
>   الأُمَوِيُّ، حَدَّثَنَا ابْنُ جُرَيْجٍ، عَنْ عَمْرِو بْنِ دِينَارٍ،
>   عَنْ عِكْرِمَةَ، عَنِ ابْنِ عَبَّاسٍ ـ رضى الله عنهما ـ قَالَ اشْتَدَّ
>   غَضَبُ اللَّهِ عَلَى مَنْ قَتَلَهُ **النَّبِيُّ صلى الله عليه وسلم**
>   فِي سَبِيلِ **اللَّهِ**، اشْتَدَّ غَضَبُ اللَّهِ عَلَى قَوْمٍ دَمَّوْا
>   وَجْهَ نَبِيِّ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم‏.
>
> Narrated Ibn `Abbas: Allah's Wrath became severe on him whom the
>   Prophet had killed in Allah's Cause. Allah's Wrath became severe on
>   the people who caused the face of Allah's Prophet to bleed.

Answer (score 0):

Allah is a unique name by itself, when we say "Allah or Ya Allah , it is not only unique but bring forth all what we can think of his attribution, as our beloved prophet said we may not be able to praise HIM than He praised Himself.

Let me also quote you the narration of Abu Huraira -  Prophet Mohammed SAAW said " there are two words ( expression or saying ) which are very dear to the Most Gracious Allah and very easy for the tongue to say 
"Subhan Allahi-wa bihamdihi - Subhan Allahil-Azim

This also increase the scale weight of each of us in the hereafter.